# ¿Estándar para crear una interfaz de usuario?

Tags: windows, interfaz-gráfica, estándares

¿Existe algún estándar para el diseño y creación de una interfaz de usuario, en especial para alguna aplicación de windows? Gracias.

Comment: no existe un estandar para el diseño, todo lo contrario, cada desarrollador o inclusive cada empresa, puede darle es estilo e imagen que desee, otra cosa es la experiencia de usuario, pero dependerá del tipo de proyecto que se va a hacer.

Comment: Puede que esto te sirva? https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/uwp/design/basics/design-and-ui-intro

Comment: Deberias de especificar la versión, si por ejemplo es windows 8 a los lineamientos se les llama metro.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres crear una aplicación para la plataforma universal de windows que sea compatible con windows, windows VR, windows phone y todas estas plataformas te recomiendo que veas esta lista de videos: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners

Está en ingles pero es oficial de microsoft y te enseñan a crear una aplicación con su interfaz propia y compatible con muchos dispositivos. Espero que esto sea lo que estas buscando.

PD: Los lenguajes usados son C# para la funcionalidad y XAML (versión modificada de HTML) para la interfaz